# RxJavaでFlowableを返すメソッドのテストの書き方について

Tags: android, kotlin, reactivex

### 概要

RxJavaのFlowableを返して尚且つそれぞれ開始・成功・失敗時に別々の値を返すメソッドのテストを書きたいのですが、テストコード上では開始時の結果しか取得できないため成功と失敗時のテストが出来なくて困っています。
この場合、どのようなテストコードが適切かどなたかご教示いただけるとありがたいです。

#### 使用環境

- AndroidStudio3.3.2
- spek1.1.5
- mockk1.9.3
- RxJava2.2.3

#### 現時点でわかっていること

- 開始時の結果しか取れない。
- 調べた資料では `awaitTerminalEvent`で 「 `onCompleted()` もしくは `onError()` が呼ばれるまで待つ」 とあったが、使用するとテストが終了しない。

  - https://hydrakecat.hatenablog.jp/entry/2016/12/12/RxJava_%E3%81%AE%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%281%29%3A_TestSubscriber%2C_test%28%29%2C_TestScheduler
- テストコードにて引数を指定して onNext() を使用すると成功時の値は取れるがテストとして意味を成さない

#### テスト結果

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Values at position 0 differ; Expected: Success(data=[TaskList(id=1, name=todo, tasks=[Task(id=1, name=aaaaa, status=DONE), Task(id=2, name=aaaaa, status=TODO), Task(id=2, name=aaaaa, status=TODO), Task(id=2, name=aaaaa, status=TODO), Task(id=3, name=aaaaa, status=TODO)])]) (class: Success), Actual: Progress(value=true) (class: Progress) (latch = 1, values = 1, errors = 0, completions = 0, timeout!, disposed!)
```

### 実装コード

```
fun getTaskLists(): Flowable<Result<List<TaskList>>> {
        // repository.loadTaskListAndTasksByDB()の結果はモックしている
        return repository.loadTaskListAndTasksByDB()
                .map {
                    TaskListTranslator.toTodoLists(it)
                }
                .toFlowable()
                .compose { item ->
                    item
                            .map { Result.success(it) } // 成功
                            .onErrorReturn { Result.failure(it) } // 失敗
                            .startWith(Result.progress()) // 開始
                            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                            .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
                }
    }
```

※ toFlowable以下の行は実際には拡張関数にしています。

- https://github.com/syo-sa1982/ToDo4Android/blob/new/usecase/app/src/main/kotlin/com/syousa1982/todo4android/domain/usecase/ToDoUseCase.kt
- https://github.com/syo-sa1982/ToDo4Android/blob/new/usecase/app/src/main/kotlin/com/syousa1982/todo4android/util/extention/ResultRxExt.kt

### テストコード

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform::class)
class ToDoUseCaseSpec : Spek({
    val taskListRepository: ITaskListRepository by lazy {
        mockk<ITaskListRepository>()
    }

    val schedulerProvider = TestSchedulerProvider()

    val todoUseCase: ToDoUseCase by lazy {
        ToDoUseCase(taskListRepository, schedulerProvider)
    }
    // repository.loadTaskListAndTasksByDB()の結果をモック
    every { taskListRepository.loadTaskListAndTasksByDB() } answers {
        val taskListAndTasks = TaskListAndTasks()
        taskListAndTasks.taskList = TaskListEntity(1, "todo")
        taskListAndTasks.tasks = listOf(
                TaskEntity(1, 1, "aaaaa", Task.Status.DONE.value.toLowerCase()),
                TaskEntity(2, 1, "aaaaa", Task.Status.TODO.value.toLowerCase()),
                TaskEntity(3, 1, "aaaaa", Task.Status.TODO.value.toLowerCase())
        )
        Single.create {
            listOf(taskListAndTasks)
        }
    }

    describe("ToDoUseCase") {
        val expectedValue = Result.success(listOf(
                TaskList(1, "todo", listOf(
                        Task(1, "aaaaa", Task.Status.DONE),
                        Task(2, "aaaaa", Task.Status.TODO),
                        Task(3, "aaaaa", Task.Status.TODO)
                ))
        ))
        // ここで期待値と比較しているが、Result.Progress()しか取れないためテストが通らない
        todoUseCase
                .getTaskLists()
                .test()
                .assertValue(expectedValue)
    }


})
```

https://github.com/syo-sa1982/ToDo4Android/blob/new/usecase/app/src/test/kotlin/com/syousa1982/todo4android/domain/ToDoUseCaseSpec.kt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[assertValue](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/BaseTestConsumer.html#assertValue-io.reactivex.functions.Predicate-) はonNextによる値が1度だけ流れてくる時に利用するメソッドです。
最初に`Result.Progress`が流れて次に目的の値が流れてくることをテストしたいならば、[assertValues](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/BaseTestConsumer.html#assertValues-T...-) を使ってみてください。

```kotlin
val expectedValue = Result.success(listOf(
    TaskList(1, "todo", listOf(
        Task(1, "aaaaa", Task.Status.DONE),
        Task(2, "aaaaa", Task.Status.TODO),
        Task(3, "aaaaa", Task.Status.TODO)
    ))
))

todoUseCase
    .getTaskLists()
    .test()
    .assertValues(Result.Progress(), expectedValue)
```

最初に`Result.Progress`が来ることはわかっていてその検証を行う必要がないなら、`skip`で飛ばしてしまうのもありかと思います。

```kotlin
todoUseCase
    .getTaskLists()
    .skip(1)
    .test()
    .assertValue(expectedValue)
```

---

それと、モック部分のコードについてですが、

```kotlin
Single.create {
    listOf(taskListAndTasks)
}
```

ここの `create` は `fromCallable` （もしくは `just`） の間違いではないでしょうか？

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。 `assertValues` を使用してみたのですが、期待値をListで渡そうとすると `Type mismach` が発生するようです。 


ですが、2つ目に提示されていた `skip` で飛ばす手法だと `Result.Success` の検証が出来ました。

モック部分についてですが、仰る通り `fromCallable` の間違いでした。
ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: 失礼しました、assertValuesの引数については回答の方を修正しておきました。ちなみに、`assertValueSequence`の方であればList型で渡せると思います。http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/BaseTestConsumer.html#assertValueSequence-java.lang.Iterable-

Comment: 重ね重ねありがとうございます。 解決できました！